# Creating a 1:1 view for every table in data warehouse ods layer

Tags: amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

I started working as a data engineer for a company where we a have a strange architecture in our Redshift cluster, and I wanted to know if this makes any sense.

We have a series of schemas, where a replicator (Attunity) is constantly updating tables as changes happen in our OLTP systems, basically creating a live mirror image of them in our warehouse ODS layer. The implementation details of this aren't important.

However, for some reason, the data architect decided that to use that data in the ODS layer, we shouldn't directly select from those tables. So instead he created a series of schemas where we have to create a view for every physical table. The views are exact 1:1 replicas, they're all basically just a `SELECT col1, col2, [...] FROM TABLE`.

It's giving us all sorts of headaches, and it's a massive maintenance overhead, because in order to get a new table from our OLTP to our OLAP, we need to provision and grant permissions to an additional component which serves no purpose (at least in my view), and whenever there is a change like an additional column in our OLTP system, we have to add it in 2 different places in our ODS layer. Essentially, there's twice as many things to manage.

Is there any technical reason why this would make sense?

Comment: The answer is very simple: "how do you handle the case if an ODS table is *renamed* or if a particuar column is *renamed*?" If the answer is you *propagate* this change in the respective view, you are right, you instroduced unnecessary overhead. Otherwise if you use the view to negate (revert) the change, you can *profit* from the additional view layer.

Comment: That is not my case... 
Our views layer must be 100% identical to the underlying physical tables at all times.
The original justification they gave had something to do with table locks being a problem if there is no view layer. But from a technical perspective, whenever you select from a view, you're not changing the fact that under the hood, you're selecting from the physical table anyway, just with a view as an intermediate step. So that explanation didn't make sense to me and to this day I'm skeptical and think the whole thing was completely unnecessary

Comment: What happens if 100 users are querying the same table? View's provide a way to prevent locks..in view you need to specify LOCK FOR ACCESS so it can prevent locking so others can read the same data